# Issue in deserializing JSONString into Java object containing list of Strings

Tags: java, json

I have a JSONString as follows:

```
{"items":[{"attribute":"grade","values":["AA"]},{"attribute":"subject","values":["mathematics"]}]}
```

I have created a class Marks as follows:

```
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Marks {
 @JsonProperty("attribute")
 private String attributeName;
 List<String> values;
}
```

While I am executing following line:

```
 List<Marks> markList = objectMapper.readValue(actionPriorityConfig, new TypeReference<Marks>());
```

I am getting following exception:

```
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not 
   deserialize instance of 
 com.amazon.avstech.autoallocation.model.AttributeAutoAllocNotEligibility out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: [{"values":["AA"],"attribute":"grade"},{"values":["mathematics"],"attribute":"subject"}]; line: 1, column: 1]
```

Comment: It's valid only @SagarRohankar

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're trying to convert it in a `Mark` objects, but `items` contains an array of `Mark`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding @JsonProperty("values") before the property values declaration.

```
public class Marks {
 @JsonProperty("attribute")
 private String attributeName;

 @JsonProperty("values")
 List<String> values;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Json String valid but it is not a Json array.

Can you change the Json array to following format and check again.

```
[{"attribute":"grade","values":["AA"]},{"attribute":"subject","values":["mathematics"]}]
```

Try following,

```
String actionPriorityConfig= "[{\"attribute\":\"grade\",\"values\":[\"AA\"]},{\"attribute\":\"subject\",\"values\":[\"mathematics\"]}]";
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

List<Marks> markList = objectMapper.readValue(actionPriorityConfig, new TypeReference<Marks>());
```